# How flexible should you make your classes?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have always wondered if I am thinking ahead too much or too little before I code something. This is especially true for me if I am not sure what possible future requirement changes I will be required to account for are. I don't know how flexible or abstracted I should make my classes. I'll give a quick example.

You want to write a program that plays blackjack against a computer and you're the type of person that likes to experiment. You begin to write the code for the deck, but then you realize blackjack could have 1, 2, 4, or any number of decks. You account for that, but then you realize that maybe the deck will be altered and not have any cards of value ten. You then decide that the deck should be completely versatile to allow any number of suits or ranks. You then decide that the rules for the deck should be able to be altered from the standard number of suits multiplied by the unique ranks to equal the total amount of cards in the deck... You can see where I am going here.

My question is this, are there any guidelines for how flexible a class should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Favor minimalism and encapsulation, avoiding functionalities you don't need.

It's of course good to design based on needs, but cluttering designs with things you do not use -- or could *possibly* use in the future -- should be minimized. It's fine to consider and implement what you are sure you will need.

When you understand and specify a 'future problem' (specifically, at that point in the future), you will often solve it different from today's solution.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the great paper "[On the Criteria to be Used in Decomposing Systems into Modules](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf)" by David Parnas, from back in **1972**.

Generally speaking, you should try to **identify areas of responsibility** that can be pushed behind a very simple interface that hides useful functionality and complexity.  You should strive to **separate the what from the how** in areas you feel are most likely to change (i.e. predicting variation).

Answer (score 2):

Flexibility is indeed are a requirement for an application / system to be maintainable. Usually I find that a design following SOLID design principle, TDD and stateless business logic is easier to maintain.

Among all of SOLID principle, I find that [S]RP is the rule that makes the application maintainable. Following [S]RP, your system will be broken down to smaller pieces, with replaceable classes. Say that it can be broken to `Deck`, `DeckRule`, `HitAction`, etc.

Interface or inheritance will help, since you can easily swap your `Deck` with `NoTenDeck` or `SpadeOnlyDeck`. And you can swap the `DeckRule` to `HardToWinDeckRule` or `ImpossibleWinDeckRule`. With `decorator` or other design patterns such as `composite` will also help to make your system flexible. Don't forget Test Unit, it will help you to refactor the code.

And also sometimes you will need something like `Breaking Change` in which you need to tear down your current architecture and interfaces to be replaced with another design.  Sometimes it is needed, but mostly not.

You can find several discussion at stackoverflow [answer for DI vs Singleton and little about state or stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315289/code-reuse-in-methods-class-vs-strategy-pattern-and-dependency-injection/17320605#17320605).

Answer (score 1):

I try to follow the agile principle of YAGNI ! - You Ain't Gonna Need It.

It isn't worth the effort of coming up with all these possible future requirements.  There are an infinite number of possible future requirements.  You can't account for all of them.  Just do what you need to do to fulfill the requirements you already have.

If in the future you get new requirements, THEN change the system. (you do have good tests to make sure you don't break anything during refactoring right?)

Answer (score 1):

**Overall thoughts on flexibility**

From your description of the problem I don't think your classes should be flexible as in *"keep throwing every new aspect of the game rules into the same class"*. A class with too many responsibilities is fragile, hard to maintain and thus hard to change - ironically, treating a class as if it were flexible will eventually make it rigid ! Don't put all your eggs in one basket. Separate concern means separate class. Your overall design should be flexible, not so much your classes.

**On the blackjack problem**

Card games, especially complex and/or evolving ones, are generally most peculiar animals and thus probably not a good standard example to start experimenting with when trying to improve your design skills.

If you want real modularity, you'll probably need a pluggable rules engine that allows plugins to hook at different stages of a game, giving you access to relevant resources to alter anything from scores to the sequence of events in a turn to even other rules.

My take on this is

- You already know your game will evolve in the future and you're going to need such an engine. To answer the "thinking ahead" part of your question, this means you'll start with a simple standard turn structure, a minimal rules engine and incrementally add to it as you implement each feature in your backlog. The thinking ahead you shouldn't do is trying to forecast every little detail in the engine upfront. In other words you'll use [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) as in `"I ain't gonna need this rule/type of hook into the game"` rather than `"I ain't gonna need a rules engine"` since you know you've got to have one anyway.

Or,

- It's going to be, at least at first, a one-shot fixed-rules game. You'll need less raw flexibility in the game system here. Concentrate on use cases and try to make acceptance tests pass with the simplest possible technical solution. Take one little step at a time. Implement a working solution for just 1 deck with simple rules at first, then expand to more complex areas. This hopefully will lead you to a no-nonsense, well-designed system which may or may not involve some kind of rules engine.

You might also want to have a look at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for game-specific design guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

When writing code I tend to look for things that may be obvious additions later on.  "Obvious is probably a word to define though. :-)     It means things that you are sure will be in a future release.  Other than that, I try not to worry about it.